# Add views programmatically in a layout and "clustered" to the center

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout and I want to do the following:
I want to place on the right of the relative layout programmatically X textviews.
X can be just 1 or can be up to 4.
What I need is that in the end I want the textviews to "cluster" to towards the center/vertically.
Examples:

```
---------------------------  RelativeLayout  Top   


TextView


---------------------------  RelativeLayout Bottom
```

With 2:

```
---------------------------  RelativeLayout  Top   

TextView-1  (the center is between Text-1 and Text-2)
TextView-2  

---------------------------  RelativeLayout Bottom
```

With 3:

```
---------------------------  RelativeLayout  Top   

TextView-1
TextView-2
TextView-3

---------------------------  RelativeLayout Bottom
```

etc.
What I tried is to create a linear layout with vertical orientation and add it to the left of the relative layout.
Then I am adding the text views as children if applicable to the linear layout but this does not work:
1) The linear layout always wraps instead of matching parent width
2) I can't seem to be able to set each child `layout_gravity` to center to test what happens because if I do:

`((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)textView.getLayoutParams()).gravity = Gravity.CENTER;`
That affects the text and not the position.
Can anyone help on this? Even a simple example with views to understand  how this is done would be great!

**Update:**  This is what I do now:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(theContext);  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutsParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);  linearLayoutsParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);  linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  linearLayout.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutsParams);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have understood, you don't need to set gravity to the `LinearLayout` childs. Just set

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

on the `LinearLayout` itself (with height = wrap_content, and vertical orientation). Something like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"

    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Programmatically (though untested):

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL); //not sure it's needed
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The linear layout rule will not propagate to its childs: LL will have equally spaced childs. But we set height to `wrap_content` so it's gonna be exactly that tall, and we set `center_vertical` so it's gonna stay centered.

Comment: How? This is what I do now: `LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(theContext); RelativeLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutsParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); linearLayoutsParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT); linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); linearLayout.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutsParams); 
`

Comment: More or less looks like you just have to add another rule: `linearLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL)`. I would also change MATCH_PARENT with WRAP_CONTENT on the height attribute.

Comment: But the current rule I have makes the linear layout itself to align to the left of the parent. If I add the new rule does it apply to the children?

Comment: Edited my answer. To better see what's going on you could activate the "layout bounds" (not really sure about the English wording) in the developer settings on your phone.